# How to check if stored procedure returned a field

Tags: delphi, ado, c++builder, vcl

I'm using some asp net stored procedures and I do not want edit them.
The trouble is when ThisProcedure returns no Field I need.

```
Query->FieldByName("RoleName") // delphi : Query.FieldByName("RoleName") (for TAG %D)
```

and sometimes it works, sometimes I've got error : CommandText does not return a return set

I can't avoid it using try catch so I have no idea how to pass this trouble.

Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FindField`, it will return nil if the field is not there.